# Object detection on Cloud using React-Native

Tags: react-native, cloud, object-detection

I need to mark diffrent objects in an image using cloud database systems and react-native.I can take  photos and store that photo using react-native image picker .What I need to do right now is sending an image to cloud system,detect diffrent objects within said image, mark these objects(for example drawing a square around each object) and then return the modified image back to my application.

I have tried using Firebase and ML kit of firebase but ML kit does not match my needs.I am struggling to find suitable object detection programs that work on cloud databases with react-native.I have checked tensor flow documentation for react native but I could not find any part about object detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on-device solution which is not merged yet https://github.com/a7medev/react-native-ml-kit/pull/20 but looks like would be. It uses ML Kit